# How to deal with spring event graph?

Tags: java, spring, events

I have a Spring application that can receive a big configuration message. We use  ApplicationEventPublisher to publish the events, and the @EventListener annotation to subscribe to them.

Different components are interested in different parts of the message, and create various objects based on it. Suppose ConfigMsg has properties A and B.

X - listens on ConfigMsg, reads A, builds XA

Y - listens on ConfigMsg, reads B, builds YB

Z - wants to get XA and YB and then refresh its state.

How can I inform Z that XA and YB are both available, given that they would get fired independently by X and Y?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell spring events listeners do not provide any advanced capabilities, when you send a message it notifies all the listeners and that's it. From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisher.html#publishEvent-org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent-)

> Notify all matching listeners registered with this application of an application event. Events may be framework events (such as ContextRefreshedEvent) or application-specific events.
> Such an event publication step is effectively a hand-off to the multicaster and does not imply synchronous/asynchronous execution or even immediate execution at all. Event listeners are encouraged to be as efficient as possible, individually using asynchronous execution for longer-running and potentially blocking operations.

So basically you can:

1. Create 3 different types of events: "ConfigMsgAvailable", "XAIsBuilt",  "YBIsBuilt",
2. both X and Y will listen on "ConfigMsgAvailable" type of events and once received will build XA and YB respectively
3. Z will listen both for "XAIsBuilt" and "YBIsBuilt" events and will store the products internally (in its internal state), the state refresh will happen only upon the availability of both XA and YB (I don't what the 'state refresh' is exactly, but assume its something from your domain and in general beyond the scope of the question)

So you'll get something like this for Z:

```
@Component // a singleton bean in spring
public class Z {
    private XA xa; // = null initially
    private YB yb; // = null initially
    ... internal state ...
    public Z() {
       // don't initialize anything    
    }   

    public void receiveXAAndTryRefreshState(XA xa) {
      this.xa = xa;
      tryRefreshState();
    } 

    public void receiveYBAndTryRefreshState(YB yb) {
      this.yb = yb;
      tryRefreshState();
    } 

    private void tryRefreshState() {
      if(this.xa != null && this.yb != null) {
        doActualRefresh();
      }
    }
}
```

Then you place 2 event listeners, the actual Spring wise implementation can vary depending on spring version, here is one option:

```
@Component
public class XAIsBuiltEventListener implements ApplicationListener<XAIsBuilt> {
    @Autowired
    private Z z;
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AXIsBuilt event) {
        z.receiveXAAndTryRefreshState(event.getXA()); 
    }
}

@Component
public class YBIsBuiltEventListener implements ApplicationListener<YBIsBuilt> {
    @Autowired
    private Z z;
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(YBIsBuilt event) {
        z.receiveYBAndTryRefreshState(event.getYB()); 
    }
}
```